# How to run Screen command on EC2 instance from Python script

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have tried launching a `EC2` instance from pycharm using a `Python` script. As part of the launch process, I have downloaded a .sh script from s3 and have executed below commands.

```
commands = [
    "aws s3 cp s3://sample/test.sh /home/ubuntu/test.sh",
    "chmod +x /home/ubuntu/test.sh",
    "sudo apt-get update",
    "./test.sh"
]
```

However, when the last command `'./test.sh'` is executed, I want to get out of the flow and create few more instances. But, as the script `./test.sh` is a long running script, its not exiting the loop. I would like to submit the job as a background `Screen` job, but, was not able to open a screen using python code snippets. I am using `paramiko` module to connect to `EC2` instance.

Comment: Are you downloading and executing the script on your local machine? Also, could you provide the snippet of code that failed to open a screen session for you?

Comment: I have downloaded the script in EC2 instance. I changed the ./test.sh to "screen -d -m ./test.sh" and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the above statement from `./test.sh` to `screen -d -m ./test.sh` and it did the trick for me.

Comment: how to stop the same or how to know which is running next time i loggin?